# Using data from json url

Tags: android, json, kotlin, gson, retrofit

I want to use data from https://www.reddit.com/top.json
but i dont know how to reach the data from array
there is like one array "data", inside this one more array "children" and only then i see my fields like name of author etc..
in app using retrofit + gson
Mb need to parse this data?
I am just learining, mb u have some sources where is written this
Here s my model class

```
data class News(
@SerializedName("title")
var title: String?,
@SerializedName("author")
var author: String?,
@SerializedName("url")
var url: String?,
@SerializedName("created")
var created: String?,
@SerializedName("num_comments")
var num_comments: String?)
```

And my Network connector

```
object NetworkService {

private const val BASE_URL = "http://www.reddit.com/top.json/"

private val loggingInterceptor = run {
    val httpLoggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
    httpLoggingInterceptor.apply {
        httpLoggingInterceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
    }
}

private val baseInterceptor: Interceptor = invoke { chain ->
    val newUrl = chain
        .request()
        .url
        .newBuilder()
        .build()

    val request = chain
        .request()
        .newBuilder()
        .url(newUrl)
        .build()

    return@invoke chain.proceed(request)
}

private val client: OkHttpClient = OkHttpClient
    .Builder()
    .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
    .addInterceptor(baseInterceptor)
    .build()

fun retrofitService(): ApiNews {
    return Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .client(client)
        .build()
        .create(ApiNews::class.java)
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

no need to pass base url for this retrofit have ability to get data from url
create interface

```
interface ClientService {
@GET
fun getData(@Url url:String): Call<Any>
}
```

than use this

```
   val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("http://www.reddit.com/").addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build()
    val service = retrofit.create(ClientService::class.java)
    service?.getData("http://www.reddit.com/top.json")
            ?.enqueue(object : Callback<Any> {
                override fun onFailure(call: Call<Any>, t: Throwable) {
                    
                }

                override fun onResponse(call: Call<Any>, response: Response<Any>) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "" + Gson().toJson(response))
                    if (response.isSuccessful) {
                       
                    }
                   
                }
            })
```

Comment: https://ibb.co/rk5S69g
https://ibb.co/wychCSK check it plz i have new problems

Comment: what is the exaxt issue can you tell you just need to copy this code into a funtion fun getData(){ here pase the retrofit class here and you got your response }

Comment: i dont know what is countyresponse

Comment: sorry my mistake let me change it now try this

Comment: much better thank you, but i still do not understand what i should put in "if" now... Sry for my skill in programming)

Comment: you just replace your reponse model from Any so you can get the data essily in response 
it.data.yourmodel. what ever you want to access